# Start activity in tab using fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, fragment, activitygroup

I have tab activities (tab1, tab2).
When button1 is pressed in tab1 activity it covers up the whole screen. How to start another activity in the same tab?

Is it possible to start `ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI` in tab1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [FragmentTabs.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentTabs.html) example in the documentation.